# What would be a good way to visualize count data (with one covariate) in an xyplot?

Tags: r, poisson-regression

I have data with around 80 observations of a count (call it our response Y) and a continuous covariate (call it X). There are only 4 levels of counts in the set though (1,2,3,4). When I plot log(Y) against X to see if there is a linear relationship between them, there is much overlap between the different response variables because there are only a few response levels and the plot becomes hard to interpret. Is there any way (preferably in R) to generate a plot that is a bit more meaningful and easy to interpret?

On the picture you can see that it's pretty hard to see if any linear relationship exists between log(Y) and X1 (note that my covariate X1 is in fact significant, so there is a strong linear relationship between the two)

[image: XY plot for count data and one covariate]

Comment: Boxplot of X1 at each level of Y?

Comment: You have about 80 $\times$ 2 data values, so why not post them for people to make concrete suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

First, the aspect ratio in your example is terrible - it's much too wide for its height.

Second, you can use a similar graph, but add jitter to log(Y).

Third, it's not clear why you are using log(Y).

Fourth  If Y takes on 4 levels and is a count, you probably should use a count regression model rather than OLS regression.

Comment: I'm fitting log(Y) against X because I'm doing Poisson regression for which log(E(Y|X)) = beta_0 + beta_1*x.